# Importing data to hbase using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, sqoop

When I want to import the data to hive using sqoop I can specify `--hive-home <dir>` and sqoop will call that specified copy of hive installed on the machine where the script is being executed. But what about hbase? How does sqoop know which hbase instance/database I want the data to be imported on?

Answer (score 1):

[Maybe the documentation helps?](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hbase)

> By specifying `--hbase-table`, you instruct Sqoop to import to a table in HBase rather than a directory in HDFS

Every example I see just shows that option along with column families, and whatnot, so I assume it depends on whatever variables that might be part of the `sqoop-env.sh`, like what the [Hortonworks docs say](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_command-line-installation/content/set_up_sqoop_configuration.html)

---

When you give the hive home directory, that's not telling it any database or table information either, but rather where Hive configuration files exist on the machine you're running Sqoop on. By default, that's set to be the environment variable `$HIVE_HOME`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that basically means that by specifing hbase/hive path in sqoop-env.sh it tells sqoop to which database Hbase/Hive I want the data to be imported(which database instance should be called by sqoop) no? Because I can have installed 3 copies or Hbase or Hive on the machine, each with different configuration, so I can choose to which concrete hbase/hive instance I want the data to be imported on right?

Comment: By specifying which configuration folders, it will read in the zookeeper quorums and Hive metastore and HDFS settings, etc. for different clusters, yes